# login with wrong information

Tags: python, python-requests

There is a personal program of mine which logs in, scrape links and then download them but I have a problem with login part. It logs in even if I enter the wrong username and password (It returns me the `You have logged in ...` sentence all the time).

> Code:

```
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import argparse 


def Login(url, login_route, username, password):

    URL = url
    LOGIN_ROUTE = login_route

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': '',
        'origin': URL,
        'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE,
    }

    request_session = requests.session()

    csrf_token = request_session.get(URL).cookies['csrftoken']

    login_payload = {
        'hidden_username': username,
        'password': password,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token
    }

    login_request = request_session.post(
        URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=headers, data=login_payload)
    
    #!
    msg = (
        f'You have logged in successfully {login_request.status_code}' if login_request.status_code == 200 else
        f'Error {login_request.status_code}' 
    )

    print(msg)
    

def get_user_input():

    url = 'https://maktabkhooneh.org/signin/?next=/dashboard/'
    username = getpass.getpass('Username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
    login_route = '/auth/login-authentication'

    return(Login(url, login_route, username, password))


def Scraper(page_url):

    Page_URL = page_url

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': ''
    }

    page = requests.get(
        Page_URL,
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

    URL_List = []
    link_count = 0
    for a_tag in soup.select('a[href^="/course/"]'):

        links = "https://maktabkhooneh.org" + a_tag["href"]

        URL_List.append(links)
        link_count += 1

    return URL_List


def Donwloader(url_list):

    URL_List = Scraper(url_list)
    download_count = 0
    for links in URL_List:
        command = f"youtube-dl {links}"
        result = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        
        #!
        if result == 0:
             download_count += 1
             return('\nReturned Value', result)

    return(f'\n{download_count} file(s) have been downloaded')



page_url = 'https://maktabkhooneh.org/course/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86-Andrew-NG-mk1085/%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D9%87-ch3364/%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86/'

Login_ = input('Login required Website [Y], [N]? ')
#!
if Login_ == 'y' or 'Y':
    get_user_input()

list_len = len(Scraper(page_url))
#!
Download_Permission = input(
    f'\n{list_len} link(s) have been extracted. Do you want to DOWNLOAD them [Y], [N]? ')
#!
if Download_Permission == 'y' or 'Y':
    Donwloader(page_url)
```

Also, I want to ask if I want to log in or not and if I want to download the extracted links but it seems there is a logical error, and actually if statements don't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you just check the status code of the server with `login_request.status_code == 200`. Even if the server sends back a page with 'Go away with your fake login' it successfully sent you a page back so you will receive a status code of 200.
Try to check the page sent back for some words like 'failed' or 'wrong' to see if the login was wrong. Or maybe se server responds with a 302 redirect if the login was correct so you can check for that?

Comment: Do you mean to check it like this: `login_request.status_code == 302`?

Comment: You are checking the wrong code. These response code is not the result of a successfull login. It's not possible to answer if a check for 302 (redirect) would work as this depends on the page you try to login to. Try to login with correct and incorrect logins and see if there is a different response. If the server always respons with 200 (ok) you have to add an additional step and parese the returned text of that page to look for a string shown when the login was correct or wrong.

Comment: Yes, it always shows 200(ok). So, you mean checking the status code is not a good approach, I have to scrape the returned text of the page when I'm logged in and check for words like `wrong` or `failed` and so on. am I right?

Comment: Correct. The response code itself just tells you that the server sent you some page back. The easiest way would be to just check for 200 to make sure you really got some page back and then check if  login_request.text.find("Login OK") will find this text on the returned page. The returned page should have a difference you can check for depending on a successful login or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it, could you please help me around the if statements too? at the end of the code

Comment: You have to change that to.   if Download_Permission == 'y' or Download_Permission == 'Y':    In you current version the if will always be executed as the second or just tests if 'Y' is true which is always the case.  Another option would be to convert your variable to upper case and just compare it with 'Y'    if Download_Permission.upper() == 'Y':